# How to identify Encoding

Tags: string, encoding, char, decode

Can you please `cout` me in which format this string is encoded

`\u041f\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0430",realty:"\u041d\u0435\u0440\u0443\u0445\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0441\u0446\u044c",hitech:"Hi-Tech",sport:"\u0421\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442",files:"\u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b\u044b",lady:"\u041b\u0435\u0434\u0437\u0456",
deti:"\u0414\u0437\u0435\u0446\u0456",health:"\u0417\u0434\u0430\u0440\u043e\u045e\u0435",travel:"\u041f\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0436\u044b",cards:"\u041f\u0430\u0448\u0442\u043e\u045e\u043a\u0456",horo:"\u0413\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043f\u044b",pogoda:"\u041d\u0430\u0434\u0432\u043e\u0440'\u0435",afisha:"\u0410\u0444\u0456\u0448\u0430",video:"\u0412\u0456\u0434\u044d\u0430`

Comment: This could be anything, but it *looks* like JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a fragment of a JSON document with Cyrillic text.